# Extracting data from HTML files using regular expressions

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I am trying to extract the specific data using regular expression but i couldn't be able to achieve what i desire, for example,

in this page

> http://mnemonicdictionary.com/wordlist/GREwordlist/startingwith/A

I have to keep only the data which is between,

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

and

```
<br /> <br /><i class="icon-user"></i>
```

SO i copied the HTML code in Notepad++ enabled Regular expression in replace, and tried replacing everything that matches,

```
.*<div class="row-fluid">
```

to delete everything before `<div class="row-fluid">`

but it is not working at all.

Does anyone knows why ?

P.S: I am not using any programming language i just need to perform this on an html code using Notepad++, not on an actual HTML file.

Comment: Parsing HTML with Regex is a bad idea

Comment: do i have any other option available ? i am doing it just to learn regex.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am not using any language i am just performing general regex command on different texts using Notepad++ i just need need to extract the particular data from html file which is opened in notepad as a souce code.

Comment: Could you use a different language?

Comment: I could use Python, if it could make regex easier to learn.

Comment: Notepad++ is fine for learning about regular expressions for searching and for search and replace. As a learning exercise manipulating HTML is probably a bad idea as it has structures that are nested and may span many lines. I suggest you learn about regular expressions by concentrating on strings that stay within one line. Perhaps a file of names and addresses, one set per line. Then search for all the "Smiths" in "London" or all the "Jones" who are not in "Oxford". Or change all the "Walkers" in "Cambridge" to be in "Manchester".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would achieve this in several steps.

**Step 1.**

transform document into one line. find

```
 \r\n
```

and replace with nothing. (make sure to select "Extended (\n, \r,..)" option in Replace dialog)

**Step 2.**

find

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

and replace with

```
\r\n~<div class="row-fluid">
```

Make sure, that character "~" not used in the document. This character wil help us to delete unnecessary lines later

**Step 3.**

find

```
<br /> <br /><i class="icon-user"></i>
```

and replace with

```
<br /> <br /><i class="icon-user"></i>\r\n
```

**Step 4.**

Delete unnecessary lines. Check "Regular expression".
find

```
^[^~].+$\r\n
```

and replace with nothing

**Step 5.**

Now you have only lines that starts with

```
~<div class="row-fluid">
```

and ends with

```
<br /> <br /><i class="icon-user"></i>
```

everything you need it's just delete this tags

PS. You can try to record a macro, if you need to do the same task several times.

Comment: If the original line breaks must be retained then you can modify **step 1**, first choose a string such as `qzq` where `zq` and `qz` do not occur anywhere in the document. Then replace line breaks (as in step 1) with `qzq`. Add a new final **step 6** that converts all `qzq` back to line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider retrieving using Xpath. Most languages support it.

There's a great firefox plugin that infers the xpath expression when you select a page item called xpather.

There's a hacked version that works for newer firefox versions here

http://jassage.com/xpather-1.4.5b.xpi

To use Xpath with python, consider using http://xmlsoft.org/python.html

Notice that Xpath may have problem with malformed html, so you may also find tidy an interesting option to "clean up" the html and get a parseable XML.

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

IMHO doing it with Notepad++ is difficult. According to [this](http://markantoniou.blogspot.be/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html), you need to:

- remove all lines (since regexps execute on each line of text)
- perform the regexp on the whole (1-line) HTML

Either you want to learn regexps, or you want to parse the HTML. SDepending on which, solution differs.

If you want to learn regular expressions, this is (again IMHO) the wrong problem to solve.

If you want to resolve the problem (keep the data between `<div>` and `<i>`), then have a look at how to parse HTML/XML. In python you have some great libraries like BeautifulSoup (which can deal with broken html). You can do it with dom parsing or a more interesting solution (and arguably better for your problem) is to use SAX and per-event processing. Since you know that after every `<div>` you'll get an `<i>`, you could do a simple stack to push all the content between the two events...